# PayPal credit card types accepted for Recurring Direct Payment

Tags: paypal

I have US based Paypal account with Business-Pro type.I need to process the recurring payment using Direct Payment Profile.I had tested its works fine.I had question the **Visa** and **MasterCard** of **customers** all over the **world** can be accepted or it has to US based only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal can help you accept payments from 203 countries, via cards of Visa, MasterCard, Amex, Discovery and so on. Please refer to below page for more details.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-country-functionality-outside

Answer (score 1):

You can accept money from customer all over the world, not limit to US .